# What terminal command or program can list an SSD's Power On Hours?

Tags: mac, terminal, hard-drive, ssd, disk-utility

I'm looking to script using the unix shell the retrieval of SSD (and HDD) data that disk utility shows in the information window.

[image: Disk Utility information]

I'm immediately interested in the Power On Hours and Power Cycle, but if all the data comes from one data structure or tool, so much the better. The usual tools `diskutil info disk0` and `ioreg -l` are not producing the "of interest" values listed in the screen shot above.

Is this information available from any of the built in OS X terminal tools or do I need to locate an open-source package that makes the same API calls to get this level of detail about a Mac drive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command that works for me in 2019 is:

```
smartctl -a disk0 | grep -i hours
```

Homebrew install is probably easiest and here are some details on installing and usage of the tool.

---

`smartmontools` is an open source package that provides most of the values you are interested in.

If you use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), install it with:

```
brew install smartmontools
```

(In the standard Homebrew installation, commands install to `/usr/local/bin`.)

Otherwise, download it from https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download and compile it as usual:

```
$ cd smartmontools-6.0
$ ./configure 
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

(Unless otherwise specified as an option to `./configure`, `smartmontools` commands install to `/usr/local/sbin`, so update the `$PATH` variable if necessary.)

The tool we are interested in is called `smartctl`.

First activate S.M.A.R.T.:

```
$ smartctl /dev/disk0 -s on
```

Then run it:

```
$ smartctl /dev/disk0 -x
```

This is an excerpt of the output, which provides a wealth of information. The values for `Power_On_Hours` and `Power_Cycle_Count` below match (once converted from decimal to hex) the ones Disk Utility reports.

```
smartctl 6.0 2012-10-10 r3643 [x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-12, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     JMicron based SSDs
Device Model:     APPLE SSD TS128C
Serial Number:    37AR11AGLTMZ
Firmware Version: CJAA0201
User Capacity:    121,332,826,112 bytes [121 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)

(...)

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     -O-R--   099   099   000    -    0
  2 Throughput_Performance  P-S---   100   100   050    -    0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--C-   100   100   050    -    0
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--C-   100   100   000    -    3237
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--C-   100   100   000    -    1485
168 SATA_Phy_Error_Count    -O--C-   100   100   000    -    0
170 Bad_Block_Count         PO--C-   100   100   010    -    8 252 82
173 Erase_Count             PO--C-   196   196   100    -    1 136 64
175 Bad_Cluster_Table_Count PO--C-   100   100   010    -    0
192 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  -O--C-   100   100   000    -    14
194 Temperature_Celsius     PO---K   072   053   030    -    28 (Min/Max 14/47)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  -O--C-   100   100   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -O--C-   100   100   000    -    0
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning

ATA_READ_LOG_EXT (addr=0x00:0x00, page=0, n=1) failed: 48-bit ATA commands not supported
Read GP Log Directory failed

SMART Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
SMART Log at address 0x00 has    1 sectors [Log Directory]
SMART Log at address 0x01 has    1 sectors [Summary SMART error log]
SMART Log at address 0x02 has   51 sectors [Comprehensive SMART error log]
SMART Log at address 0x06 has    1 sectors [SMART self-test log]
SMART Log at address 0x09 has    1 sectors [Selective self-test log]
SMART Log at address 0x80 has   16 sectors [Host vendor specific log]
(...)
SMART Log at address 0x9f has   16 sectors [Host vendor specific log]
SMART Log at address 0xe0 has    1 sectors [SCT Command/Status]
SMART Log at address 0xe1 has    1 sectors [SCT Data Transfer]

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log (GP Log 0x03) not supported

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Extended Self-test Log (GP Log 0x07) not supported

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       1 (0x0001)
SCT Support Level:                   0
Device State:                        Active (0)
Current Temperature:                    28 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     22/30 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     14/47 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0
SCT Temperature History Version:     2
Temperature Sampling Period:         1 minute
Temperature Logging Interval:        1 minute
Min/Max recommended Temperature:      5/40 Celsius
Min/Max Temperature Limit:            0/70 Celsius
Temperature History Size (Index):    128 (77)

Index    Estimated Time   Temperature Celsius
  78    2012-11-29 19:48    25  ******
 ...    ..(  7 skipped).    ..  ******
  86    2012-11-29 19:56    25  ******
  87    2012-11-29 19:57    26  *******
 ...    ..( 19 skipped).    ..  *******
 107    2012-11-29 20:17    26  *******
 108    2012-11-29 20:18    27  ********
 ...    ..( 16 skipped).    ..  ********
 125    2012-11-29 20:35    27  ********
 126    2012-11-29 20:36    28  *********
 ...    ..(  7 skipped).    ..  *********
   6    2012-11-29 20:44    28  *********
   7    2012-11-29 20:45    29  **********
   8    2012-11-29 20:46    29  **********
   9    2012-11-29 20:47    28  *********
 ...    ..( 67 skipped).    ..  *********
  77    2012-11-29 21:55    28  *********

SMART WRITE LOG does not return COUNT and LBA_LOW register
SCT (Get) Error Recovery Control command failed

Device Statistics (GP Log 0x04) not supported

ATA_READ_LOG_EXT (addr=0x11:0x00, page=0, n=1) failed: 48-bit ATA commands not supported
Read SATA Phy Event Counters failed
```

To end, deactivate S.M.A.R.T.:

```
$ smartctl /dev/disk0 -s off
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using the built-in `system_profiler` command?

```
system_profiler -listDataTypes
system_profiler SPSerialATADataType
system_profiler -xml SPSerialATADataType
```

Newer Macs have NVMe drives and not SATA drives, so you'd start with `system_profiler SPNVMeDataType` to get BSD Names and other data that's not as detailed as the power on hours. The `smartctl -a disk0 | grep -I hours` command from smartmontools is the ideal command line tool for more details on storage hardware.

Comment: These do not contain the data I seek on my 2011 Air.

Comment: It doesn't list that data on `system_profiler SPNVMeDataType` either, but +1 for the idea to check and explaining how to use the tools